# How to find user location using cell tower?

Tags: android, location

How to find the user location using the cell tower in Android, or how to get the cell location based on the Cell ID in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class MyLocationActivity
     extends MapActivity {
    MapController mapController;
    MyPositionOverlay positionOverlay;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        // Configure the map display options
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.setStreetView(true);
        mapView.displayZoomControls(false);
        mapController.setZoom(17);
        // Add the MyPositionOverlay
        positionOverlay = new MyPositionOverlay();
        List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        overlays.add(positionOverlay);
        LocationManager locationmanager;
        String context=Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationmanager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(context);
        String provider=LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        Location location= locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }
    private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            positionOverlay.setLocation(location);
            Double lat=location.getLatitude()*1E6;
            Double lon=location.getLongitude()*1E6;
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(),lon.intValue());
            mapController.animateTo(point);
        }
        else{


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using last known location can lead to very inaccurate results.  Be careful.

Comment: Does this require GPS?

Comment: this is required GPS? i want to get location without using GPS if any solution please provide solution. thanks

Comment: Where is cell tower information used in the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to register for location updates.  You indicate which level of granularity you want by specifying a provider. For cell tower updates, use the [NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER).

Answer (score 2):

and MyPositionOverlay is also here.....

```
public class MyPositionOverlay extends Overlay {
    private final int mRadius = 5;
    Location location;

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if (shadow == false) {
            // Get the current location
            Double latitude = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
            Double longitude = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
            GeoPoint geoPoint;
            geoPoint = new GeoPoint(latitude.intValue(),longitude.intValue());

            // Convert the location to screen pixels
            Point point = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(geoPoint, point);
            RectF oval = new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y - mRadius,
                point.x + mRadius, point.y + mRadius);

            // Setup the paint
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setARGB(250, 255, 0, 0);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
            Paint backPaint = new Paint();
            backPaint.setARGB(175, 50, 50, 50);
            backPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            RectF backRect = new RectF(point.x + 2 + mRadius, point.y - 3*mRadius,
                point.x + 65, point.y + mRadius);

            // Draw the marker
            canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
            //canvas.drawLines(pts, paint);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(backRect, 5, 5, backPaint);
            canvas.drawText("I am here", point.x + 2*mRadius, point.y, paint);
        }
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is not related to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can find LAC (location area code) From cell tower By API ericsson

https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-location/documentation