# How to get current tower location from network operator on android

Tags: android, networking

i want to current get tower location address like nokia mobiles display current tower location in home screen like operator name and tower address displayed on mobile.i want to like below:

***SIM OPERATOR NAME***

***CURRENT TOWER ADDRESS***

i want get these details in offline on android!

Can anyone help me with greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check this question [Get Cell Tower Locations - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668271/get-cell-tower-locations-android)

Comment: @BBdev thanks for reading my question ,i am already tried it's not return current tower address!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  [get cellid](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/get-location-of-cell-id-from.html)

Hope it will helpful to you.

Below is the content taken from the original URL in case original page becomes unavailable.

---

Get location of Cell ID, from opencellid.org using HttpGet().
    A class OpenCellID was created to handle the http communication with opencellid.org. To simplify the job, request with "fmt=txt" is sent, such that we can simply splite the result to retrieve our latitude, longitude.

```
To know more about the project OpenCellID, refer to last post.

Get location of Cell ID, from opencellid.org using HttpGet()

We need the following permission in this example:
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET


package com.AndroidTelephonyManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidTelephonyManager extends Activity {

 public class OpenCellID {
  String mcc;  //Mobile Country Code
  String mnc;  //mobile network code
  String cellid; //Cell ID
  String lac;  //Location Area Code

  Boolean error;
  String strURLSent;
  String GetOpenCellID_fullresult;

  String latitude;
  String longitude;

  public Boolean isError(){
   return error;
  }

  public void setMcc(String value){
   mcc = value;
  }

  public void setMnc(String value){
   mnc = value;
  }

  public void setCallID(int value){
   cellid = String.valueOf(value);
  }

  public void setCallLac(int value){
   lac = String.valueOf(value);
  }

  public String getLocation(){
   return(latitude + " : " + longitude);
  }

  public void groupURLSent(){
   strURLSent =
    "http://www.opencellid.org/cell/get?mcc=" + mcc
    +"&mnc=" + mnc
    +"&cellid=" + cellid
    +"&lac=" + lac
    +"&fmt=txt";
  }

  public String getstrURLSent(){
   return strURLSent;
  }

  public String getGetOpenCellID_fullresult(){
   return GetOpenCellID_fullresult;
  }

  public void GetOpenCellID() throws Exception {
   groupURLSent();
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet request = new HttpGet(strURLSent);
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
   GetOpenCellID_fullresult = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
   spliteResult();
  }

  private void spliteResult(){
   if(GetOpenCellID_fullresult.equalsIgnoreCase("err")){
    error = true;
   }else{
    error = false;
    String[] tResult = GetOpenCellID_fullresult.split(",");
    latitude = tResult[0];
    longitude = tResult[1];
   }


  }
 }

 int myLatitude, myLongitude;
 OpenCellID openCellID;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       TextView textGsmCellLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gsmcelllocation);
       TextView textMCC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mcc);
       TextView textMNC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mnc);
       TextView textCID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cid);
       TextView textLAC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lac);
       TextView textGeo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.geo);
       TextView textRemark = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.remark);

       //retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

       String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
       String mcc = networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
       String mnc = networkOperator.substring(3);
       textMCC.setText("mcc: " + mcc);
       textMNC.setText("mnc: " + mnc);

       int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
       int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
       textGsmCellLocation.setText(cellLocation.toString());
       textCID.setText("gsm cell id: " + String.valueOf(cid));
       textLAC.setText("gsm location area code: " + String.valueOf(lac));

       openCellID = new OpenCellID();

       openCellID.setMcc(mcc);
       openCellID.setMnc(mnc);
       openCellID.setCallID(cid);
       openCellID.setCallLac(lac);
       try {
   openCellID.GetOpenCellID();

   if(!openCellID.isError()){
    textGeo.setText(openCellID.getLocation());
    textRemark.setText( "\n\n"
      + "URL sent: \n" + openCellID.getstrURLSent() + "\n\n"
      + "response: \n" + openCellID.GetOpenCellID_fullresult);
   }else{
    textGeo.setText("Error");
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   textGeo.setText("Exception: " + e.toString());
  }
   }   
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/gsmcelllocation"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/mcc"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/mnc"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/cid"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/lac"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/geo"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/remark"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the name of the Current Network Operator to which the Android phone is currently connected is to get hold of the android.telephony.TelephonyManager and get it from there:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

String simName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();