# Trace mobile service provider name

Tags: android, service-provider

I have been assigned a task to access mobile service provider name instead of location. I searched and referred to many things. But I couldn't find. All are shown about the location (that is latitude and longitude values) and some of them shows the network provider name. I need something like Cell Info Display Name.

```
Example: If I'm using Vodafone Network it will display the service provider name that my mobile is currently using.
```

I don't need to display location and place in map. I just exactly need to show the service provider name. Is there any method? Can anyone please explain via sample code?

Comment: see this link at once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643244/how-to-get-current-tower-location-from-network-operator-on-android

Comment: Its not shown clearly. I want to display the tower name not operator name

Comment: u can't see tower name all u can get is , its cell id

Comment: From cell id how to identify the place?

Answer (score 5):

```
// Returns the alphabetic name of current registered operator

public String getServiceProvider() {

      TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)
      getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

      String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName(); // alphabetic name of current registered operator

      return carrierName;
}
```

Example Output: 
Vodafone

Comment: it's always better to describe your answer rather than just posting a code

Comment: @user4010519 if I am using dual sim mobile means, how can I get the both carrier name?

Answer (score 2):

please check with the following code

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceID =telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        String deviceID1 =telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
        String deviceID2 =telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```

Get your CELL ID : 
http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/06/get-location-of-cell-id-from.html  use this link..

from above link you will Get location of Cell ID, from opencellid.org using HttpGet().

**Edit 2**

Hi see below link in the same type of question have been discused there .

[Get Cell Tower Locations - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668271/get-cell-tower-locations-android)

Comment: no. I want to get the result as Tower area (i.e place name where the tower is)

Comment: for that you need to get the current location .. and then need to do reverse geo coding.. so you will get the current area..

Comment: hi see my edited post link.. from that you will get cell id. and location.. so try from that

Comment: hi, from reverse Geocoding I'll get the location. Not the tower name. Anyway I'll try

Answer (score 1):

Use This code, It will give you your **service provider** name :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: will it provide the tower name? I think it will display the provider name only

Comment: Yes this method will only provide you the service provider name. So you want the tower name also with the service provider name.

Comment: I want to display the tower name only. Its won't do that

Comment: you can't get tower name directly. you can get only cell id . you have to find a way to get tower name using cell id.